# PHPhotoLibrary - overwrite bunch of photos without or with one confirmation alert

Tags: ios, iphone, camera-roll, phphotolibrary

The task is to sync set of images in a custom album on iPhone with content of the app. So they are created by the app, and then user can change something inside the app, and all images should be modified.

The problem is that [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html) asks when we need to modify photo. Is there any workaround to have only one confirmation alert for all images or no confirmation alerts at all?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After some research, answered by myself :)

If we delete assets by one PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets block it shows only one confirmation alert.

```
        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:[PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:myAlbum options:nil]];
        }
                                      completionHandler:nill];
```

[image]